# HTTPS to HTTPS reverse proxying

Tags: 16.04, apache2, virtualhost, https

I have an ubuntu server v 16.04 with apache installed. I want to reverse proxy a web server. To be exact i would like to reverse proxy the OWA of my mail server. Internet users hit the url https://mail.company.com which redirects the traffic to my firewall at port 443. Then i forward this type of traffic to my ubuntu server (reverse proxy server) at port 1443. So i would like to know how to configure the virtual host of apache to reverse proxy the traffic to the mail server OWA.

I run apache2 and i have already tried many that i found on the internet.

Whatever i tried i receive connection timed out or connection refused or error empty response.

Comment: I think you have to configure the reverse proxy at the https://mail.company.com web server not on your backend web server. Also see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

Comment: How can i reverse proxy a server from its own. I think this url does not fit me. It says only for http examples and nothing for https

Comment: The backend server in my scenario is the mail.company.com server